# Show that $\{e_n\}_{n≥2}$ is an orthonormal system in $span(x_0,e_n)_{n≥2}$ which is not complete.

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, orthogonality

> Consider $x_0 = (1/j)_{j≥1} \in l^2(\mathbb{N})$ and $e_n$ the usual canonical vectors of $l^2(\mathbb{N})$. Then $E = span(x_0,e_n)_{n≥2}$ is  a  pre-Hilbert  space.   Show  that $\{e_n\}_{n≥2}$ is  an orthonormal system in $E$ which  is not complete. However, if $f \in E$ and $f⊥e_n$, for all $n≥2$, then $f= 0.$

Can you help me with this proof?

My specific question is in the part "Show that $\{e_n\}_{n≥2}$ is an orthonormal system in $E$ which is not complete." I have to prove that $\{e_n\} ⊥ E$ and, clearly $||\{e_n\}||=1$ but also, how can I define a Cauchy sequence in this to prove the incompleteness?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The orthonormal set $\{e_n\}_{n\ge 2}$ is not a  basis of $E$ since
$$
x_0-\sum_{n=2}^\infty \langle x_0,e_n\rangle e_n=e_1\ne 0,
$$
where
$$
x_0=\left(1,\frac{1}{2},\ldots,\frac{1}{n},\ldots\right).
$$
Note that $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \langle x_0,e_n\rangle e_n\in E$, since
$$
\sum_{n=2}^\infty |\langle x_0,e_n\rangle|^2= \sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}<\infty.
$$
But so does 
$$
w=x_0-\sum_{n=2}^\infty \langle x_0,e_n\rangle e_n
$$
and
$$
w\perp e_n,\quad\text{for all $n\ge 2$},
$$
while $w\ne 0$.

Answer (score 0):

The completeness in that case means that $\overline{\text{span}(e_{n})_{n\geq 2}}\ne E$. Note that every finite linear combination of $(e_{n})_{n\geq 2}$ has the first entry $0$, so does their limit, so $x_{0}$ does not belong to $\overline{\text{span}(e_{n})_{n\geq 2}}$.